# How to run Oban jobs locally?

Tags: cron, elixir, elixir-oban

How can I run Oban jobs (I am using a Cron job plugin with Oban) on localhost so that I can see it is working?

My Oban's just run a query and then create a file at a location. I want to be able to test this on localhost or which ever correct method there is for testing this.

```
defmodule ObanJobOne do
   def job(_) do
     """
     some sql query
     """
     |> IO.inspect
     |> //do some mapping
     |> //create file
   end
end
```

How can I run `ObanJobOne` so that I can see the results of the sql query with the `IO.inspect` and also see the file that got created.

Answer (score 2):

Oban jobs are just modules. You can use `iex -S mix` to test them locally:

```
YourWorker.perform(%Oban.Job{args: %{"id" => 1}})
```

If you want to test the queue itself, use:

```
%{id: 1}
|> YourWorker.new()
|> Oban.insert()
```

Oban also supports `ExUnit` with [`Oban.Testing`](https://hexdocs.pm/oban/Oban.Testing.html).